# Sentence formation using do not

Tags: sentence-construction

I have prepared a report and don't want to show one piece of information to the client. I want to tell my friend this. If I say...

> *We don't show this in the report. Otherwise xyz will happen.*

...is my sentence formation correct?

I don't want to use *should not / need not / can not / will not* in the sentence.

Comment: For reference: "don't".

Comment: Also, *information* is not normally a countable noun; we don't say "one information".  You would have to say "one *piece of* information".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a matter of grammatical rules as such, but personally I don't like the "double negation" involved in juxtaposing ***not show + otherwise***. That aside, consider these simpler examples...

> 1) *Don't move **or** I'll shoot* [(1530 written instances in Google Books)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Don%27t%20move%20or%20I%27ll%20shoot%22)
>    2) *Don't move **otherwise** I'll shoot*. [(**one** written instance)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Don%27t%20move%20otherwise%20I%27ll%20shoot%22)
>    3) *Stop! **Or** I'll scream!* [(297 written instances)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stop%20or%20I%27ll%20scream%22)
>    4) *Stop! **Otherwise** I'll scream!* [(**no** written instances)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stop%20otherwise%20I%27ll%20scream%22)

...where obviously #2 and #4 are vanishingly uncommon compared to #1 and #3, regardless of whether the *first* "alternative" involves a negated verb form.

---

In OP's *exact* context, I also don't like the use of ***will*** for the *hypothetical/counterfactual* second alternative. Again, I'm not convinced it's actually "ungrammatical", but I think ***would*** is far more idiomatic when referring to a "theoretical possibility" that (in context) ***definitely won't happen***. Taking those two points into account, the smallest change to make OP's example idiomatic for me is...

> 5) *We don't show this in the report, **or** xyz **would** happen.*

...but I think on purely *semantic* grounds I'd rather use a conjunction that more accurately expresses the relationship between the two alternatives...

> 6) *We don't show this in the report, **because** xyz would happen [if we did].*

Note that when the first alternative is expressed in the negative as above, it's completely optional whether to explicitly specify ***if we did*** [include it in the report] because it's contextually obvious (if the first alternative is **NOT X**, the second one is usually just the non-negated **X**). But if the first alternative *isn't* negated, you'd normally need to be more explicit for clarity...

> 7) ?*We put that in the report or the auditors would complain.* (to me, "less-than-ideal")
>     8) *We put that in the report because otherwise the auditors would complain.* (better)
>     9) *We put that in the report because the auditors would complain if we didn't.* (best)

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you don't want to use *should not* or *shouldn't*. Your sentence would make more sense if you did.

> "We shouldn't show this in the report. Otherwise xyz will happen."

You can say something similar, though, if you add *want to* after the *don't*:

> "We don't **want to** show this in the report. Otherwise xyz will happen."

Comment: I simply took OP at his word that he didn't want to use ***shouldn't*** precisely *because* that conveys a somewhat different meaning (people often actually *do* do things they *shouldn't*, or *didn't want to do*, but obviously they *never* did things they *didn't* do).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Oh! I see how you're reading the original now. Interesting.

Comment: This looks like yet another of those cases where I failed to read and take into account the question ***title***. If I'd done that I probably wouldn't have posted an answer at all (most likely I'd have closevoted as "Unclear" or "Proofreading"). But I would also just add that the actual question text does start with *I **have prepared** a report*. This implies OP just wants to convey the bare fact that *something contextually relevant **isn't** in the report* - which he then justifies/explains (it doesn't seem to be asking the addressee for advice or approval).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree this was a hard question to interpret. Kudos to both of us, though, for taking a stab at it and trying to help the learner.

Comment: The issue ***I*** mainly addressed was that ***otherwise*** is idiomatically unlikely in the construction *[obey this imperative] **or** [something bad will happen]*, which I think could be useful to many learners. And the issue your answer raises for me (a possible difference between *You shouldn't do that* and *You don't want to do it*) also looks like it could be interesting/useful for the broader audience. It's just a shame we didn't have decent questions to post them against!